My like button doesn't change its state after clicking
I have a problem and honestly lost hope already.
I created a like button, what supposed to change its state after clicking.
And it doesn't work. I need your help, please.
it must change a color, when post is liked. now it's just grey. counter of likes works perfectly, but color is still the same, no matter if user likes on unlike post.
this is my code:
Widget buildLikeButton(String userId, String postId) {
  Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool currentIsLiked) async {
    if (!currentIsLiked) {
      await addLike(postId, userId);
      setState(() {
        likeCount++;
        isLiked = true;
      });
    } else {
      await removeLike(postId, userId);
      setState(() {
        likeCount--;
        isLiked = false;
      });
    }
    return !currentIsLiked;
  }

  return FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: checkIfLiked(userId, postId),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Icon(Icons.error); // Obsługa błędów
      }
      isLiked = snapshot.data ?? false;

      return Row(
        children: [
          LikeButton(
            isLiked: isLiked,
            onTap: (liked) async {
              return await onLikeButtonTapped(liked);
            },
            size: 25.0,
            circleColor: CircleColor(
              start: Color(0xffFFC0CB),
              end: Color(0xffff0000),
            ),
            bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
              dotPrimaryColor: Color(0xffFFA500),
              dotSecondaryColor: Color(0xffd8392b),
              dotThirdColor: Color(0xffFF69B4),
              dotLastColor: Color(0xffff8c00),
            ),
            likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
              return Icon(
                isLiked ? Ionicons.heart : Ionicons.heart_outline,
                color: isLiked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                size: 25,
              );
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8), // Odstęp
          FutureBuilder<int>(
            future: getLikesCount(postId),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('Ładowanie...');
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('0'); // Obsługa błędu
              } else {
                likeCount = snapshot.data ?? 0;
                return Text(
                  '$likeCount',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}


Are you running this code in a stateless or stateful widget ChaNefer? Stateful widgets, unless you use different state management solutions like Get, allow you to 'rebuild' the widget and change the button color after its clicked.

Can you provide the implementation of LikeButton? It would be better if you could provide a minimum reproducible code.

My enpoint checking if a post is liked was working incorrectly and returning incorrect information, which is why the button status did not refresh. Thank you for your reactions, I will probably come back here more than once. :)

Not sure about flutter, but traditional web can use javascript and css to achieve this with a couple lines of code.
